# Odd twitter bootstrap tooltip behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put tooltips on divs in an attempt to explain a user interface I'm working on.

On the right div the tooltip shows up just fine, and exactly how I want it to.

[image: Working tooltip]

On the other end of my UI is a tooltip that ends up covering the whole div! I want it to display like the other div displays.

[image: Bad tooltip! It's covering the whole DIV even when I told it not to!]

Here is the html for both

Working Version:

```
  <div id="percentCompleteDiv"
                   class="container top-profile well text-center"
                   style="border-radius:3px;"
                   data-placement="right"
                   data-trigger="manual"
                   data-content="Displays the completion percentage
                   progress of the current upload"
                   data-original-title="Completion Percentage"
                   rel="popover">
                <h4 style="color:#555;">Complete Pct:</h4>
                <h3 id="uploadpercent">0%</h3>
              </div>
```

Not-working version:

```
<div class="container text-center well"
               data-placement="left"
               data-trigger="manual"
               data-content="Displays the current cost of this Job.
               For more information on pricing see our pricing page"
               data-original-title="Estimated Cost"
               rel="popover">
```

How do I get it to display on the left properly?

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS associated with this?  The default Bootstrap seems to work as expected. http://jsbin.com/aPegIhaQ/2/edit

Comment: I'm using a lot of them, i dunno. I manually overrode the CSS to get what I wanted. Changed left and width now it looks fine.